# Customized buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using xeditable for my project.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/11276/)

Above is the fiddle.

I want to have **save and send invite** button instead of **save** button only while click on add button.

When I click on edit it should be **Save** button.

I tried using another forom to display save and send invite button with no result.

```
<form editable-form name="rowform" id="hidebuttons12" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" shown="">
    <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel(); isCollapsed2 = !isCollapsed2" ng-hide="hideButton[$index]" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="saveUser(); isCollapsed2 = !isCollapsed2" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-hide="hideButton[$index]" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</form>

<form class="text-right" editable-form name="rowform1" ng-show="rowform1.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" shown="inserted == user">
    <button type="button"  ng-click="removeUser($index);" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="saveUser(); sendInvite(); isCollapsed2 = !isCollapsed2" ng-disabled="rowform1.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">{{buttonText}}</button>
</form>
```

Or can we have all three buttons in one form and hide and show it based on button click.

Can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :** Following your comment, new Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/11280/

The same way, you just need to add : `ng-show="user.id < 0"` to the save button

---

I updated your fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/11278/

I'm not an expert in xeditable so maybe there is a better solution.
The solution I used is setting `user.id = -1` when you add new user.

And setting `user.id = users.length+1` only during save.

Therefore you can use `ng-show="user.id < 0"` on the button you want to show only for new users.

***Code:***

```
$scope.saveUser = function (data, user) {
    //$scope.user not updated yet
    user.id = $scope.users.length + 1;
    angular.extend(data, {
        id: user.id
    });
    return $http.post('/saveUser', data);
};

// add user
$scope.addUser = function () {
    $scope.inserted = {
        id: -1,
        name: '',
        status: null,
        group: null
    };
    $scope.users.push($scope.inserted);
};
```

***View:***

```
<button type="button" ng-show="user.id < 0" ng-click="saveUser(); sendInvite();" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">Send invite</button>
```

Comment: @Steevan Updated the fiddle for you. But I think it was so easy you could have done it yourself ;) If (user.id < 0) means it's a new user, then you just need to add `ng-show="user.id > 0"` to the save button to remove it from new users view

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer.

Comment: Iggy Iam unable to save any data.

Comment: @User123 what do you mean ?

Comment: While adding new user are you able to save it?